# How can I get my refresh token to work with the Spotify API using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, spotify

I am currently trying to work with the Spotify API using the Authorization Code Flow. I have used the Spotify passport strategy to pull an `accessToken` and a `refreshToken`, but whenever I make an axios call to pull a new accessToken using the refreshToken I get a 400 error. Here is the code that I am using to make the call: (Also I am making this app using create-react-app)

```
  getAccessToken() {
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
      params: {
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token: this.state.user[0].refresh_token
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'applicaton/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(`${process.env.CLIENT_ID}:${process.env.CLIENT_SECRET}`)
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Verify that you are sending the `accessToken`. I suspect that `this.state.user[0].refresh_token` is undefined.

Comment: By the time that the call is made this.state.user[0].refresh_token is defined as the refreshToken belonging to the user.

Comment: Verify that the request has all required params via Network tab. Alternatively, you should inspect the response body, look for `error_description` and `error`

Comment: The network tab shows this as the error information:

 {error: "server_error", error_description: "Unexpected status: 400"}
error
:
"server_error"
error_description
:
"Unexpected status: 400"

Also, the url that is shown in the console reads:
 https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token={refreshToken off of state}

Comment: Did you verify you're sending the required params?

Comment: https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/

Comment: I am using the headers that are outlined in the above documentation

Comment: I am fully aware of that, but I am saying, inspect the request using the DevTools Network tab or via a proxy like Fiddler4

Comment: Did you check that the params are being sent encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? That endpoint doesn't accept JSON.

Also, you shouldn't let your client secret end up in your frontend. It should remain on your backend, with no access to external parties. Otherwise, your oauth client could be compromised. You should handle refreshes and code exchanges on the server.